# Rails no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to save a data inside bookmark variable but it's throwing an error which is described in the title.Please Tell me what am I doing wrong I can't understand the error.

```
  bookmarks = Bookmark.where(request_id: bookmarked_against_Request[:_id])
    if bookmarks
          bookmarks[:corsponding_requests] << request_bookmarked[:id]
    else
      bookmarks_new = Hash.new
      bookmarks["owner_req"] = session[:user]
      bookmarks["request_id"] = data
      bookmarks["corsponding_requests"] = Array.new
      bookmarks["corsponding_requests"] <<  request_bookmarked[:_id]
      Bookmark.createBookmark(bookmarks)
    end
```

[image: rails error]

PS:-  I HAVE CHANGED BOOKMARKS TO BOOKMARKS_NEW IN THE ELSE BLOCK BUT IT STILL THROWING THE SAME ERROR

Comment: You can try my solution, hope it will help.

Comment: Please don't put images of text in questions.  Instead, put the text itself.  It's much nicer to read and work with as text.

Comment: There's no image of text in it @WayneConrad

Comment: `![rails error](http://i59.tinypic.com/290r8ft.png)`

Comment: oh I am really sorry that image did'nt load when I opened this page I'm really sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bookmarks = Bookmark.where(request_id: bookmarked_against_Request[:_id])

if bookmarks
  bookmarks.each { |bookmark| bookmark.update_attributes(corsponding_requests: request_bookmarked[:id] }      
else
  bookmark = Hash.new
  bookmark["owner_req"] = session[:user]
  bookmark["request_id"] = data
  bookmark["corsponding_requests"] = Array.new
  bookmark["corsponding_requests"] <<  request_bookmarked[:_id]
  Bookmark.createBookmark(bookmark)
end
```

Comment: well it again started to give me error and now I just found out what was the real error

Comment: It's nice that you found out the error. What was the problem and what you tried to fix that?

Comment: In the Model the data type was not right and instead of Array I had written Aray and now I completely what was wrong and your solution helped me to. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine `bookmarks` like array, and when you try  `bookmarks[:corsponding_requests]` ruby "think", that you want acces to array element through integer index (for example like `bookmarks[1]`) but it can't convert symbol to integer and throw an error. Maybe, it helps you...

Comment: even if I am getting one element due to where condition ?
Will bookmarks still be considered an array ?

Comment: Yes, `where` return array. You can use `Bookmark.where(request_id: bookmarked_against_Request[:_id]).first` to get one element